# UITabBarController's selectedViewController not selecting correct UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
```

I used above code to select a tab for `UITabBarController`, The code selecting correct tab but the view for the tab is still first view. So how can i select both tab and view from code. When i select the selected tab again then only the view is changing to correct view. so how to solve this problem.

Comment: In this case it seems like it'd be simpler to use `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;`  Don't know if it will change the results, but it might.

Comment: Could you add the code where you put your viewControllers please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is a UITabBarController, just do this :

```
[self setSelectedIndex:3];
```

Comment: Yes, my class is a UITabBarController. Your code working with me.

Comment: Can i set images for each tab from the same class?, if yes how can i change?

Comment: [[[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"finishedImage"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectedImage"]];

Answer (score 0):

I think this LOC does all the trick:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```